# context.putImageData() Not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, use-effect

Im trying to create a drawing application in react, its working for the most part. But when i try add an undo button it doesnt work.

I try make the undo button with this `finishDrawing()` function, where i use getImageData and store it in an array called `restore_array`

```
    const finishDrawing = () => {
        //console.log(contextRef.current)
        contextRef.current.closePath()
        setIsDrawing(false)
        //restore_array.push(contextRef.current.getImageData(0, 0,400,256+80))
        setIndex_array(index_array + 1)
        setRestore_Array((prevState) => { return [...prevState, contextRef.current.getImageData(0, 0,400,256+80)]})
        console.log(restore_array, restore_array.length)
        
    }
```

then when a Undo button is clicked i try to reload this image in the `restore_array` with a `useEffect` which should re-render the entree canvas with the previous image

```
    function undoLast() {
        console.log(restore_array[index_array], index_array, restore_array)
        if (index_array > -1) {
            setIndex_array(index_array-1)
            restore_array.pop()
            setLines(!lines)

        }
        //contextRef.current.putImageData(restore_array[index_array-1], 0, 0)   
    }
```

and

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect 3c')
        console.log(restore_array)
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        context.lineWidth = thick
        context.lineCap = "round"
        context.strokeStyle = colour
        if (restore_array.length === 0) {
            console.log('empty')
            return
        }
        //context.clearRect(0,0,400,256+80)
        //context.fillRect(0,0,400,256+80)
        context.putImageData(restore_array[index_array], 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 256+80)
        contextRef.current = context
    }, [lines])
```

Does anyone know why my `putImageData` isnt working in this case?

Heres my entire code for reference

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";



function DrawCanvas() {

    const canvasRef = useRef(null)
    const contextRef = useRef(null)
    const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false)
    const [colour, setColour] = useState('black')
    const [prcolour, setPrColour] = useState(null)
    const [thick, setThick] = useState(3)
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const [restore_array, setRestore_Array] = useState([])
    const [index_array, setIndex_array] = useState(-1)
    const [clear_, setClear_] = useState(true)
    const [lines, setLines] = useState(true)
    //let restore_array = []





    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth/1.5 ;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight/1.5 ;
        canvas.style.width = `${window.innerWidth/3}px`;
        canvas.style.height = `${window.innerHeight/3}px`;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        context.scale(2,2)
        context.lineCap = "round"
        context.lineWidth = 3
        context.strokeStyle = "black"
        //const img = DogImage
        context.fillStyle = 'gray'
        context.fillRect(0,0,400,256+80)
        contextRef.current = context
        
    }, [])




    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect 1a')
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        context.lineWidth = thick
        context.lineCap = "round"
        context.strokeStyle = colour
        contextRef.current = context
        document.getElementById(colour).style.borderColor = 'gray'
        if(prcolour === null) {
            return
        }
        document.getElementById(prcolour).style.borderColor = 'black'
        document.getElementById(prcolour).style.borderWidth = '3px'

    }, [colour])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect 2b')
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        context.lineWidth = thick
        context.lineCap = "round"
        context.strokeStyle = colour
        const Dogimage = new Image();
        Dogimage.src = '../../images/dog-without-labels.png'
        Dogimage.onLoad = () => {
            console.log('load image')
            context.current.drawImage(Dogimage, 0, 0,400,256+80);
        }
        contextRef.current = context
    }, [thick])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect 3c')
        console.log(restore_array)
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        context.lineWidth = thick
        context.lineCap = "round"
        context.strokeStyle = colour
        if (restore_array.length === 0) {
            console.log('empty')
            return
        }
        //context.clearRect(0,0,400,256+80)
        //context.fillRect(0,0,400,256+80)
        context.putImageData(restore_array[index_array], 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 256+80)
        contextRef.current = context
    }, [lines])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect 4d')
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        //contextRef.fillStyle = 'gray'
        context.lineWidth = thick
        context.lineCap = "round"
        context.strokeStyle = colour
        context.clearRect(0,0,400,256+80)
        context.fillRect(0,0,400,256+80)
        contextRef.current = context
    }, [clear_])

    


    function undoLast() {
        console.log(restore_array[index_array], index_array, restore_array)
        if (index_array > -1) {
            setIndex_array(index_array-1)
            restore_array.pop()
            setLines(!lines)

        }
        //contextRef.current.putImageData(restore_array[index_array-1], 0, 0)   
    }

    const clearCanvas = () => {
        setClear_(!clear_)
    }



    const startDrawing = ({nativeEvent}) => {
        const {offsetX, offsetY} = nativeEvent
        contextRef.current.beginPath()
        contextRef.current.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY)
        setIsDrawing(true)

    }

    const finishDrawing = () => {
        //console.log(contextRef.current)
        contextRef.current.closePath()
        setIsDrawing(false)
        //restore_array.push(contextRef.current.getImageData(0, 0,400,256+80))
        setIndex_array(index_array + 1)
        setRestore_Array((prevState) => { return [...prevState, contextRef.current.getImageData(0, 0,400,256+80)]})
        console.log(restore_array, restore_array.length)
        
    }

    const draw = ({nativeEvent}) => {
        if (!isDrawing) {
            return
        }
        const {offsetX, offsetY} = nativeEvent;
        contextRef.current.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY)
        contextRef.current.stroke()
    }

    const colourChange = (value) => {
        setPrColour(colour)
        setColour(value)
    }

    const thickChange = (event) => {
        setThick(event)
    }
      
      
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="left">
            
            
                <canvas className="canvas" onMouseDown={startDrawing}
                        onMouseUp={finishDrawing}
                        onMouseMove={draw}
                        ref={canvasRef}/>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
            <h5><dt>Chart Draw</dt></h5>
            <p>Use your finger or your mouse to draw directly on the chart opposite.</p>

            <button className="draw">Draw</button>
            <button className="select">Select</button>

            <p><dt>Line thickness: {thick} </dt> </p>
            <input className="slider" type="range" min="1" max="19" value={thick} class="slider" id="myRange" step="1" onChange={(event)=>thickChange(event.target.value)}></input>
            
            <button className='red' id='red'onClick={() => colourChange('red')}>  </button>
            <button className='black' id='black'  onClick={() => colourChange('black')}>  </button>
            <button className='yellow' id='rgba(204,153,0,255)' onClick={() => colourChange('rgba(204,153,0,255)')}>  </button>
            <button className='blue' id='rgba(1,102,255,255)' onClick={() => colourChange('rgba(1,102,255,255)')}>  </button>
            <button className="undoButton" onClick={()=>undoLast()}> <dt> Undo/Back a step</dt></button>
            <button className="undoButton" onClick={()=>clearCanvas()}> <dt> Clear canvas</dt></button>
            <button className="savecloseButton"> <dt>Save and Close</dt></button>

        </div>
    </div>
    )

}

export default DrawCanvas;
```

Comment: Is it possible you intended to tag the question with `javascript` instead of `java`?

Comment: shoot sorry my bad

Comment: Not very familiar with react-js and I don't see anything obviously wrong in the JS, but if your drawing app isn't going to use a lot of bitmap image sources, then you're probably better storing an Array of drawing commands instead of still ImageData like that. In no time your memory consumption will explode here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works "OK" for me...
*I think it's obvious that your `putImageData` in function undoLast is commented.

I'm assuming that was intentional, not the actual problem.*

---

We can see it working here:
[image]

Yes only part is getting the undo.
That is because you have hardcoded values in the getImageData:

```
setRestore_Array((prevState) => { 
  return [...prevState, contextRef.current.getImageData(0, 0,400,256+80)]
})
```

That only gets a portion of the canvas, so only that portion is getting restored...
if you needed the entire canvas, change that to use the canvas dimensions.
Something like:

```
setRestore_Array((prevState) => { 
  return [...prevState, contextRef.current.getImageData(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height)]
})
```

---

Also you should look at what [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081504/context-putimagedata-not-working-in-react/72132176#comment127366473_72081504) mentioned, he has a good point:

> storing an Array of drawing commands will cause your memory to explode

For your approach using image data my recommendation is to limit the undo to a fix amount, like 10 and discard older, that will guarantee a cap on memory consumption and prevent any out of memory errors.

Comment: Actually my comment in the `undoLast` was the problem. but this helped!

Comment: @gitmcgee I'm glad I could help... next time try to reduce your code to a minimal example, that helps get more attention to your question, questions with a lot of code are quite often ignored ... read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That's not what my comment was meant to convey. My point is that storing full ImageDatas will blow the memory. They should instead only store the drawing commands in a js Array. E.g, for a lineto 10, 30, you'd store `["l",10,30]` instead of storing an ImageData containing all RGBA channels of every pixels of the context.

Comment: And having an undo functionallity that remembers only the 10 last actions won't be that useful to anyone either.

Comment: Sorry @Kaiido but that is just your point of view... most of the people using undo in a drawing application is for a few last mistakes, even the mighty Photoshop comes with a small default of history states (20): https://youtu.be/k3bx_VL_AnY?t=102